How can I automate the installation of binary dependencies in Python on a Linux environment?
I have a Python program that accepts the insertion of Python modules.
These modules can call binaries (Nmap for example).
Each module has a file in which these dependencies are described (in this case it would contain a line "nmap=7.94").
I use a virtual environment, a requirements.txt file and pip to manage the Python dependencies, but I don't know how to manage binary dependencies in the same way.
I'd like to use Python to automate the installation of binary dependencies, is there a clean way to do that ?

It depends on the platform's package manager. The best way to go would be to have a native package for your python app that depends on the other packages.
